# installation of octave with gui

Tags: user-interface, installation, octave, ubuntu-16.04

I know this is very noobish question but only way to get through this is ask for help.
So here it is, I installed *octave-4.2.1* from  *octave-4.2.1.tar.xz* by following standard procedure of extracting , *./configure*, *make* , *make install* etc. It seems only *octave-cli* is installed when I fire *octave--force-gui* nothing happens. My question is what all I must do in order to get *octave-gui* working? also if it's not installed how can I install it without hampering *octave-cli*?

Comment: ./configure detects which libraries are present. If (for example in your case) there are no libs for Qt, it disables the GUI and shows a message at the end. Btw, if you build stuff from source on GNU/Linux you really should read the warnings/error messages which ./configure prints at the end. Follow the instructions here to install the dependencies: http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Debian_systems

Comment: And of course the way for "normal user" would be to use `apt-get install octave` or use a PPA which might give you an older release (perhaps 4.0) but you don't have to bother with compiling from source and struggling with dependencies

Comment: did you solve your problem? I might be able to help.